# Connecting to Tor via infected android phone (hotspot)

Tags: tails, malware

So I the only way I have access to Internet right now is via my android phone, I am pretty sure it's compromised because the adversary is a bunch of people with high technical knowledge. I tried to wipe the partitions and install a clean rom but this isn't the topic I want to discuss here.

I only use Tails os, so all the traffic is encrypted, my concern is can that traffic be intercepted and/or deciphred when it goes through my phone?

As far as I understand the purpose of tor is to encrypt packets sent and received from my machine, how likely is a hacker can read that data and know what websites I'm connecting to?

Tails give me peace of mind since it runs on ram and I do not have setup the persistence storage feature so all I'm worried about is the data in the tor browser?

For the sake of simplicity and because I don't have enough details about the type of attack, let's say I install an app like wireshark or similar on my android phone, what type of data can I get?

Answer (score 0):

All the communication and such are encrypted before leaving tails, so if you sniffed it on the phone you would not see the unencrypted data. Same scenario as if your ISP would sniff data from a regular internet connection from your house while you use tor, or someone on your home network sniffing data while you use it.

Another attack angle would be malware on the phone that then infects the computer that the phone is plugged into, but that is a different scenario though, and doing that towards tails is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If yoo're using a *clean* client, i.e. a fresh Tails installation or a live usb one - no, you're safe. Even in case of the sophisticated hack case - just use a full-blocking incoming firewall for a Tails base and put the Tor into the `ClientOnly 1` mode